# Split and catch text by a variable delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I have a text which include delimiter tags in the following format:

```
<\!--[od]+-\d+--\>
```

Example:

```
<!--od-14-->
<!--od-1--\>
<!--od-65--\>
```

I need a regex which will split the text and catch the \d+ numeric argument in the split, also the text after it.

Here's a regex i come up, the problem is it does not return multiple lines.

https://regex101.com/r/xvw8Xw/2

Comment: Please post your regex text with your post. Its bad practice to direct the reader somewhere to read your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to make the dot match a newline using for example an inline modifier `(?s)`. Then use a non greedy match with a positive lookahead to assert the next comment or the end of the string:

```
(?s)<\!--[od]+-(\d+)-->(.*?)(?=<!--|$)
```

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, make the dot match a newline
- `<\!--` match `<!--`
- `[od]+-(\d+)-->` Match 1+ times either o or d (which might just be od)
- `(.*?)` Match any char 0+ times except a newline  non greedy
- `(?=<!--|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is `<!--` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jzc3Bx/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/BMALT)

For example using `/s` in the pattern:

```
$re = '/<\!--[od]+-(\d+)-->(.*?)(?=<!--|$)/s';
$str = '<!--od-1--> cdskc sdkjc 
dsd
sk<!--od-2-->cscdscsdcsd 
cdscs

csdcsdc
<!--od-432-->cdcdscsd';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression might also work here on `m` mode:

```
<!--od-(\d+)--\>([\s\S]*?)(?=<|$)
```

or this one on `s` mode:

```
<!--od-(\d+)--\>(.*?)(?=<|$)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SjXqTd/1)

#### Test

```
$re = '/<!--od-(\d+)--\>(.*?)(?=<|$)/s';
$str = '<!--od-1--> cdskc sdkjc 
dsd
sk<!--od-2-->cscdscsdcsd 
cdscs

csdcsdc
<!--od-432-->cdcdscsd';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```